# How to access a dynamic disk on a Win 7 computer

Tags: windows-7, dynamic-disk

I have two hard drives that are used as dynamic disks on a Windows Server 2008R2 in a software RAID 1 (mirroring).
As I understand, Windows 7 (Pro / Ultimate) can also handle dynamic disks.

If I take one of the hard drives, put it into an external enclosure (USB) and connect it to the Windows 7 computer, how can I then access the files on the dynamic drive?

In computer management, I see options to convert it into a basic drive, but that's not what I want to do.
The content of the drive should not change in any way, I only want to copy files off the drive.

Later on, the drive goes back into the Windows Server to be used as before.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it’s not possible. You should however be able to connect both of the disks inside the computer.